# division in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do a simple division of variables in a shell script, but it is somehow not working. May be there I am overlooking something really basic. Below is a script for calculating total number of reads from a bam file for bams files read from a list file. I need to assign the output to a variable and calculate a ratio. This is what I have:

```
normNum=100000
while IFS=$'\t' read -r bamfile name; do
#for i in $(ls *.bam)
echo $bamfile
mappedReads="$(samtools idxstats $bamfile | awk '{s+=$3} END {print s}')"
echo $normNum
echo $mappedReads
#scalingFactor="$((normNum / mappedReads))"
#echo $scalingFactor
scalingFactor=`printf "%0.3f\n" $((normNum / mappedReads))`
echo $scalingFactor
done < "${file}_temp"
```

The different prints are giving my correct number except for scalingFactor, which gives me 0.

```
merged_DupRem.bam
100000
24226512
0.000
```

Any pointers please?

Thanks..

Comment: BashFAQ #22: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022

Comment: BTW, you've got a bunch of quoting bugs (and `for i in $(ls *.bam)` is basically one huge bug; use `for i in *.bam` instead, and read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: *All* expansions should be quoted, barring a quite limited set of exemptions. `"$bamfile"`, not `$bamfile`; `"$scalingFactor"`, not `$scalingFactor`; etc -- otherwise field splitting and glob expansion take place on variable contents, so you don't know how many words they'll expand to if you have filenames with spaces, or if prior code executed in the same shell established an IFS value with non-whitespace characters that exist within your filenames.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy , I will keep the quote in mind. ls was commented out but still I get your point. Thanks a lot for pointing these as I am still a novice in shell scripting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash does `integer` math, not floating point. You will need to use `awk` or `bc` to provide floating point output. e.g. with `bc`

```
scalingFactor=$(printf "scale=3; %d/%d\n" $normNum $mappedReads | bc)
```

Comment: Might quote the expansions -- that way if either value expanded to more or less than a single word we'd get a more useful error message rather than either an unuseful one or a surprising result (ie. multiple lines of bc script generated, as would occur with more than two arguments to that printf).

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I didn't know that it doesn't work for floating points.